# Is it possible to redirect a user to a page populated by data from the previous page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a vanilla PHP directory comprising of queried MySQLi information but I want to make it so that on the press of a button it would dynamically take the information from whatever button I clicked and populate the a redirect page with that information.

The problem being, no matter where I look I can't figure out how to achieve that, $_GET & $_POST don't seem to be the way to go, any pointers?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: pointer: $_GET/$_POST is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path, maybe you just missed something. Here is an example using POST:

**HTML**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="myButton" value="myValue1">Click Me!</button>
   <button type="submit" name="myButton" value="myValue2">Click Me!</button>
   ...
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$whichButton = $_POST['myButton'];
echo $whichButton; // myValue1 or myValue2
```